# Jquery/Javascript target in function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that I am calling with two images like so.

```
$('#image1').bind('click',doNext);
$('#image2').bind('click',doNext);
```

I need to be able to tell which one called the function.

```
function doNext(){
if(target == $('#image1'){
   alert('image1');
     }else{
   alert('image2');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` within `doNext` will be the raw DOM element, so:

```
function doNext() {
   if (this.id === "image1") {
       alert('image1');
   }else{
       alert('image2');
   }
}
```

There I'm branching on the `id` because you specifically did that in your code, but usually you just interact with the object.

If you need to use any jQuery functions, wrap the raw DOM element in a jQuery object (`var $this = $(this);`), but you don't need to if all you want to do is look at the `id` as I did above.

Within jQuery event handlers, there are (at least) two significant DOM elements you have access to: The element on which you hooked the event (`this`), and the element that *triggered* the event (`event.target`). In your case, assuming that `image1` and `image2` are `img` elements, they'll be the same because `img` can't contain any other element, but in the case of elements that can contain other elements (`div`, `p`, etc. — e.g., most elements), `event.target` may be different from `this`. Say you have:

```
<div id="foo">
   <p>Blah blah blah</p>
</div>
```

and this

```
$("#foo").click(function(event) {
    alert(this.tagName);
    alert(event.target.tagName);
});
```

If you click the paragraph, you'll get

```
DIV
P
```

...because you hooked the event on the `div`, but it was triggered by a click on the `p`. (This is the basis of event delegation.)

Answer (score 1):

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
if (id == 'image1') {
   alert('image1');
} else{
   alert('image2');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function to retrieve the ID of the element.  Also, I would further simplify this by adding a common class to both images so that you can do this:

```
$('.myimages').click(function() {
    if($(this).attr() == 'image1') {
       alert('image1');
    } 
    else {
       alert('image2');
    }
});
```

Comment: Using `attr` to retrieve `id` is overkill in a big way. `id` is a reflected property on the DOM instance.

Comment: It's inefficient (it's unlikely to *matter*, but it's inefficient). If all you're doing is looking for the `id`, there's no reason for long string of function calls and memory allocations involved in wrapping the DOM element in a jQuery instance and then calling `attr` on it, which hands off to about four other functions before eventually realizing it can...look at the `id` property on the raw element.

Comment: I completely agree that your solution is much more efficient.  But in the grand scheme of things, both yours and mine are drops in the bucket.  :)

Comment: Kon: Indeed yes, in the context of a click it's a distinction without a difference. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use event.target:

```
function doNext(event){
if($(event.target).attr('id') == 'image1'){
   alert('image1');
     }else{
   alert('image2');
    }
}
```

Comment: `event.target` is very different from the element where the event was *hooked*. In this specific case, because they're `img` elements, it's fine, but if they were anything else, you'd probably end up looking at the wrong element (a `span` within it, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, i usually used event.target but now i understand better when i should use this

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `event.target` in the event handler function:

```
function doNext(event) {
    var target = event.target;
}
```

Alternatively, `this` will refer to the clicked element:

```
function doNext() {
    var clickedID = this.id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#image1').click(function(){doNext('image1')});
$('#image2').click(function(){doNext('image2')});
});

doNext = function (target){
if(target == "image1"){
   alert('image1');
     }else{
   alert('image2');
    }
}
```